# GRE Coordinate Geometry Question

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Question: In the xy-plane, the point with coordinates (−6,−7) is the center of circle C.
The point with coordinates (−6, 5) lies inside C, and the point with
coordinates (8,−7) lies outside C. If m is the radius of C and m is an
integer, what is the value of m ?

Comment: I'm not sure how knowing what's inside and what's outside the circle allows me to find its radius.

Comment: If you find the distance from the center to each point, you can determine upper and lower bounds on the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$m > 12$ and $m < 14$; we also know $m$ is integer. Therefore $m$ is?